# Database setting before being advanced for criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, search

I am creating a picture based website for my high school. I was wondering how I should approach my database in terms of searching.

I plan on having search criteria for searching pictures. I would like to add more search criteria's later on into my database.

Is this the proper way to do it. Or should or can I only put all the search criteria from user inputs now. Will it be too difficult adding further user specific input search criteria later on?

****Should I be using MySQL? what are my options?

Comment: You have asked too many broad questions in a single post. I doubt anyone will be able to really help you until you produce some code or suggest what are you view points or ideas which you think should be implemented.

Comment: when people upload pictures, I will have checkboxes to check. When people search my site I will have those checkboxes attached to the search button.This is what I mean

Comment: Can you give us an example of what information the checkboxes would contain and how they would be used for search? Are you planning to include text-based search as well?